# Is there any risks of upgrading our SQL server 2008 R2 from SP2 to SP2

Tags: administration, sql-server, farm, sharepoint-farm, sql-server-2008

We have the following settings insdie our farm :-

- SharePoint Enterprise server 2013, on separate windows server 2008 R2 VM.
- SQL server 2008 R2 with SP2, on separate windows server 2008 R2 VM.

now we want to install SQL server 2008 SP3 inside our sql server. so the sql server DB will be upgraded from SP2 to SP3? so is there any risks of doing so ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no risk to applying the SP3 on the SQL server 2008. But you have to plan it.I would apply the patches in the following order.

- Schedule a Downtime for the SharePoint
- I will stop the IIS & timer services so that no connection should make to SQL server while patching. (In one of farm I shut down the server)
- Apply the Patch to SQL server, test and verify it.
- Bring the SharePoint Server back online.
- Test it.

I would not do this one directly from Production, I will test it in the Test environment 1st.

Comment: so you mean it is better to turn the whole sharepoint server down while installing the  SP3 on sql server ? what will be the effect if i do not shut the sharepoint server ???

Comment: If SharePoint make a connection to content DB during the patching...may be no information returned to customers, or delayed information or some of time it can corrupt the database, or fail your upgrade....so a lot of unknowns

Comment: i will do the SP-3 installation on our test server first, although our test server is a single VM which contain both SQL & SharePoint .. but i think if SP3 will cause any problem it will be reveled on our test.. but generally speaking installing service pack for DB should not cause problem,, as they will not affect the databases structure and data (again speaking generally .. is this correct ??)

Comment: yes that's correct

Comment: ok i will install on test .. if everything went well ,,, will do on live.. thanks